# Why is meta returning wrong type for cols which start with a string value

Tags: kdb

I am just curious why when a col starts with a string and a value of a different type, meta will set t="C", but if it starts with symbol or float or int and a value of a different type it will show a mixed (null) type.

```
q)meta ([]col1:(`dwadw;`dawdawd);col2:123 344f) // correct
c   | t f a
----| -----
col1| s
col2| f

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

q)meta ([]col1:(`dwadw;123i);col2:123 344f) // correct
c   | t f a
----| -----
col1|
col2| f

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

q)meta ([]col1:("dwad";123i);col2:123 344f) // would expect type=" " for col1
c   | t f a
----| -----
col1| C
col2| f
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [https://code.kx.com/q/ref/meta/#:~:text=Only%20the%20first%20item%20in%20each%20column%20is%20examined](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/meta/#:%7E:text=Only%20the%20first%20item%20in%20each%20column%20is%20examined).

*"Only the first item in each column is examined."*

`meta` aims to work as a quick summary, it does not deeply inspect everything to avoid the speed penalty.

You can inspect tables in other ways to check all values in an untyped column to see what mix of data is there:

```
distinct each type each'flip([]col1:("dwad";123i);col2:123 344f)
col1| 10 -6h
col2| ,-9h
```

Comment: ok . so if it looks at the first item in each column, why does it display the correct type for situations where the first elem is symbol. It shows a mixed type not 's'. same for any other elem that's not string.

Comment: A mixed column will be type 0h. A list of all symbols would be 11h. If it sees a symbol in the first row but the column is 0h it knows that the column must be a mixture of types.